# SSIS package recording to log file, when they shouldn't

Tags: sql-server, ssis, error-logging

Our IT people are complaining about the log entries growing on our 2016 SQL Server database.   I've tried to limit the logging, but everything I do doesn't seem to help. We are still seeing message types of

```
onpostexecute
onpostvalidate
oninformation
etc
```

I've gone to the separate parts of the package and made sure everything was turned off.
I've also tried to limit it to basic logging on the SSISDB property
but, I still get every part showing messages.. and, filling up our logs

[image]

am I missing something here?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your first screenshot, someone with the `ssis_admin` role or a sysadmin can change the retention window from the default 365 days to whatever your organization defines as a valid retention period. The next time the job kicks off (midnight if memory serves correctly), it'll prune out the old data but you can do that by hand if so desired.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-catalog-properties-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-ver16

The second screenshot is the legacy Package Deployment Model's logging mechanism which is less accessible in the Project Deployment Model as Project has a better, more native way of handling this.

When you run a package, either one-off right click and run package or define a job, you have the ability to define the logging level

[image]

With 2017+, you can actually create custom logging levels https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-stored-procedures/catalog-create-customized-logging-level?view=sql-server-ver16 which you can then reference as needed.

Were it me, I'd dial back the retention window and not muck about with logging levels. Dollars to doughnuts, as soon as you drop the logging to not include an attribute, you'll have an exception where you'll have needed that bit of information to swiftly triage the problem.